# Randomly assigning columns to other columns in R

Tags: r

I have a column of student names and a column consisting the group number for each of those students. How could I randomly assign each student to be a judge of another group's work, could anyone let me know on how to build a function to solve that issue? They cannot be a judge of their own group.

```
Bob Ross 1

Kanye West 1

Chris Evans 1

Robert Jr 1

Bruce Wayne 2

Peter Parker 2

Steven Strange 2

Danny rand 2

Daniel Fisher 2

Rob Son 3

Son Bob 3

Chun Li 3

Ching Do 3

Ping Pong 3

Michael Jackson 4

Rich Brian 4

Ryan Gosling 4

Nathan Nguyen 4

Justin Bieber 4
```

Comment: Does every student get a group to judge? (so groups have multiple judges?) Does each group need the same number of judges?

Comment: Yes, all students get a group to judge, and every student is in exactly one group. Each group doesn't need to have the same number of judges. Can assume there are 20 students too if that makes it easier?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, using `tidyverse` methods. Basically this says for each value (`map_int`) in `group`, take a `sample` from the groups that aren't the current one.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(name = c("Kanye West", "Chris Evans", "Robert Jr", "Bruce Wayne", "Peter Parker", "Steven Strange", "Danny rand", "Daniel Fisher", "Rob Son", "Son Bob", "Chun Li", "Ching Do", "Ping Pong", "Michael Jackson", "Rich Brian", "Ryan Gosling", "Nathan Nguyen", "Justin Bieber"), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
df %>%
  mutate(
    to_judge = map_int(
      .x = group,
      .f = ~ sample(
        x = unique(group)[unique(group) != .x],
        size = 1
      )
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>    name            group to_judge
#>    <chr>           <int>    <int>
#>  1 Kanye West          1        4
#>  2 Chris Evans         1        2
#>  3 Robert Jr           1        3
#>  4 Bruce Wayne         2        1
#>  5 Peter Parker        2        3
#>  6 Steven Strange      2        3
#>  7 Danny rand          2        4
#>  8 Daniel Fisher       2        1
#>  9 Rob Son             3        1
#> 10 Son Bob             3        2
#> 11 Chun Li             3        4
#> 12 Ching Do            3        4
#> 13 Ping Pong           3        4
#> 14 Michael Jackson     4        2
#> 15 Rich Brian          4        3
#> 16 Ryan Gosling        4        1
#> 17 Nathan Nguyen       4        2
#> 18 Justin Bieber       4        1
```

Created on 2018-09-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `tidyverse` would be to `group_by` the `group` column, define the sample vector with `setdiff` and draw a sample of the size of the group:

```
df <- data.frame(Student = LETTERS[1:20],
                 Group = gl(4, 5))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Judge = sample(setdiff(unique(df$Group), Group), n(), replace = T))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   Group [4]
   Student Group Judge
   <fct>   <fct> <chr>
 1 A       1     4    
 2 B       1     2    
 3 C       1     3    
 4 D       1     3    
 5 E       1     4    
 6 F       2     4    
 7 G       2     4    
 8 H       2     1    
 9 I       2     1    
10 J       2     4    
11 K       3     4    
12 L       3     2    
13 M       3     1    
14 N       3     2    
15 O       3     2    
16 P       4     2    
17 Q       4     1    
18 R       4     2    
19 S       4     1    
20 T       4     3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! another question is if one of the students dropped the class, how could I change the function so that if any amount of students drop the class it will still work? As well how could i store the judge results onto a data frame? Thanks again!